# Short story about man who time travels by crossing folds in his map. He meets a young woman and falls in love with her

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

This was in a magazine around 2000. A man gets in his car and realizes he drives to a different time by crossing the folds in his map. He meets a young woman who he falls in love with. He’s a old man and becomes young when he crosses the folds of his map.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of "[Mrs. Todd's Shortcut](http://www.abovetopsecret.com/forum/thread1116033/pg1#pid20682833)".